# MySQL Query not selecting data based on WHERE value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to return all records from my database where the `userID` is equal to the logged in user.

I have the following only for some reason its not returning anything, can anybody see any obvious errors?

```
<?php 
$interestsquery  = "SELECT * 
                      FROM user_interests 
                     WHERE user_id = $usersClass->userID()";
$result = mysql_query($interestsquery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row['interest']}";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Obvious that your PHP is not catching MySQL errors so you could debug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method call is a complex enough expression that you should probably enclose it in expression interpolation delimiters:

```
$interestsquery  = "SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = {$usersClass->userID()}"
```

But I also recommend abandoning the primitive PHP/mysql extension and moving to PDO, so you can use query parameters.  Then you don't have to hassle with string interpolation at all, and you gain better habits for writing code that resists SQL injection vulnerabilities.

```
$interestsquery  = "SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = ?"
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($interestsquery);
$result = $stmt->execute(array( $usersClass->userID() ));
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, Im still learning PHP so im very new to a lot of the things Im seeing here, would it be wise to read up on PDO now or wait until I understand the entire fundamentals of PHP first?

Comment: PDO is really not that hard.  I recommend using PDO and forgetting that the plain mysql extension exists.  I wish that they'd deprecate the mysql extension.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't call functions and have them parsed that way. You'll either need to concatenate manually, or set a variable and parse that.

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = " . $usersClass->userID();
```

Or this:

```
$uid = $usersClass->userID();
"SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = $uid";
```

Comment: or  `"SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id = {$usersClass->userID()}";` but still he should be using the quoting function

Comment: yea... I don't like calling functions inside strings (Yes, I know it's different, but... somehow...)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$interestsquery  = "SELECT * FROM user_interests WHERE user_id =".$usersClass->userID();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$interestsquery  = "SELECT * FROM user_interests 
                    WHERE user_id = ".$usersClass->userID();
```

And make sure `$usersClass->userID()` returns a valid integer user id.